# How to solve a matrix for the span of columns.

Tags: matrices

[image]

Having trouble with the problem shown above ^. I put that matrix and solved it in it's reduced echloen form and got this:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -13 \\
0 & 1 & 6\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

But I don't know how this helps me because the answer is:
[image]

How did they get that answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the reduced Echelon form to the $augmented$ matrix:  $$
\begin{bmatrix} 
2 & 5 & 4 & b_{1}\\
1 & 2 & -1 & b_{2}\\
-1 & -1 & 7  & b_{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

This will give $$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & -13 & -2b_{1}+5b_{2}\\
0 & 1 & 6 & b_{1}-2b_{2}\\
0 & 0 & 0  & b_{1}-3b_{2}-b_{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$

Thus the solution to the system will be $x_{1}-13x_{3}=-2b_{1}+5b_{2},$ $x_{2}+6x_{3}=b_{1}-2b_{2}$ and $b_{1}-3b_{2}-b_{3}=0.$ In other words, provided that $b_{1}-3b_{2}-b_{3}=0$ then there will be infinitely many solutions. See [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/alg/augmentedmatrix.aspx) for examples of augmented matrices.

Comment: thanks dude i had a feeling i had to put them variables in first